# Declaring int array and changing its elements in C inside a for loop

Tags: c, printf, address-operator

I am new to C and currently learning arrays. I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    int available[6];
    for(int o=1; o<=3; o++){
        available[o]=20;
        printf("%d\n",&available[o]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which is supposed to output (in my understanding):

```
20
20
20
```

Now the problem is that it outputs:

```
2293300
2293304
2293308
```

Am i missing a crucial part and did some silly mistake?. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Some silly mistake. `&available` -> `available`. Enable and read compiler warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   printf("%d\n",&available[o]);
```

Here you are printing the address, because `&` gives the address of the following value, change it  to:

```
   printf("%d\n",available[o]);
```

to print the value inside the array.

Comment: does the ```&``` always outputs the address of the array element regardless if its an int or char?

Comment: `&` gives the address of what follows.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d\n",&available[o]);
```

`&available[o]` is a pointer to the memory address of `available[o]`.

You need to omit the `&` operator to gain the value of `available[o]`, not its address.

---

Since you also provided an argument of wrong type (`int *`) for the `%d` conversion specifier which expects an argument of type `int`, the program invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior):

> "*d, i The `int` argument is converted to signed decimal in the style[-]dddd. The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear; if the value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it is expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is1.The result of converting a zero value with a precision of zero is no characters.*"
>
> Source: C18, 7.21.6.1/8 - "The fprintf function"

---

> "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. 288) **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined**."
>
> "288) See "future library directions" (7.31.11)."
>
> Source: C18, 7.21.6.1/9 - "The fprintf function"